# Decoding H.264 stream from dvr

Tags: stream, ffmpeg, h.264, wireshark

I have a security DVR that uses h264 streams.  I have been trying to get this to work with zoneminder.  I have successfully logged into the dvr and recieved some form of data streams.  The data stream is dumped to a fifo/pipe, and then zoneminder uses ffmpeg to read this in.

Note:  i know very very little about h.264 streams.  just enough to be stupid.

The video only updates about every 15 seconds in ZM.  I can dump the stream to a file with ffmpeg or avconv (avconv -i /tmp/mypipe cam.mp4) but it is still not right.  However, the file created by avconv is WAY WAY better than the one created by ffmpeg.

I've included a link to the wireshark dump (I did change the PW and login info, etc...).  From the data, It appears that the dvr is adding a header to the h264 data streams.  I understand that the h264 stream starts with a (0x00 00 01 67) or (0x00 00 01 61).  Here is an example of the header plus start of stream:

```
0x33, 0x30, 0x64, 0x63, 0x48, 0x32, 0x36, 0x34, 
0x3f, 0x55, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 
0xa2, 0x7a, 0xea, 0xdc, 0xcf, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x0d, 0x0a, 0x11, 0x07, 0x13, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x67, 0x42, 0xe0, 0x14, 
0xdb, 0x05, 0x87, 0xc4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 
0x68, 0xce, 0x30, 0xa4, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x01, 0x06, 0xe5, 0x01, 0x51, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x01, 0x65, 0xb8, 0x00, 0x01, 0xa8, 0xac,
```

I can see that there are a few frame indicators in this message.  The DVR's header appears to be 32 bytes long in this case, and in some other messages in the dump, it appears to be 24 bytes long.  I am striping the header off before I dump the stream to the pipe. (I have verified the output doesn't include the dvr's headers in any way.

What I would like help with is determining what I should be sending to the pipe.  should I start with the first h.264 key?  Is there something out of order?  I'm very surprised that ffmpeg is only getting 15 second updates, but avconv is much better (lots of dropped frames, and playback is "sped up".

using ffmpeg to read the pipe produces a file that shows it's codec as:  H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part  10) (avc1) with a Decoded format:  Planar 4:2:0 YUV using vlc.

Appreciate any help you can provide!

[Wireshark h264 dump](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7515347/MPout_test1_chopped.pcap)

edit: on Ubuntu 13.04
ffmpeg version:   6:0.8.6-1ubuntu2
avconv 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-1ubuntu2

Comment: You're using libav, and their so-called `ffmpeg` does not have sane defaults for mp4 output unlike `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg (and I presume `avconv` too).

Comment: so perhaps I could swap the "ffmpeg" that is there now with "real" ffmpeg...  even so, the video, while much much better, is still not truly usable.  pixelates and jumps a bit

Comment: I guess what I really need to know is if the stream dump I posted actually is in the right format, or if the DVR manufacturer did some things to the stream.